Не запускается exe файл после native компиляции
Приложение WinUI3. После компиляции в VS приложение развертывается, запускается и работает.
Выполняю компиляцию через командную строку командой: dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release, после чего в папке publish создается exe файл, но не запускается.
в диспетчере задач видно появление фонового процесса с названием приложения и сразу же исчезает, никаких всплывающих окон не появляется.
Что нужно сделать, чтобы файл запустился?
.csproj


<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net9.0-windows10.0.26100.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <RootNamespace>TerminalQuikClient</RootNamespace>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
    <Platforms>x86;x64;ARM64</Platforms>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetFrameworkVersion('$(TargetFramework)')) &gt;= 8">win-x86;win-x64;win-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetFrameworkVersion('$(TargetFramework)')) &lt; 8">win10-x86;win10-x64;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>

    <WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>
    
    <TrimmerSingleWarn>false</TrimmerSingleWarn>
    <PublishAot>true</PublishAot>
    <EnableCoreMrtTooling Condition=" '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' != 'true' ">false</EnableCoreMrtTooling>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <WindowsSdkPackageVersion>10.0.19041.38</WindowsSdkPackageVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion>10.0.19041.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.29.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Net.Client" Version="2.67.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools" Version="10.0.26100.1742" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.6.241114003" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="2.0.2.45" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="9.0.0" />
    <Manifest Include="$(ApplicationManifest)" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>



В событиях виндовс:
Имя сбойного модуля: Microsoft.UI.Xaml.dll, версия: 3.1.6.0
Путь сбойного модуля: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.6_6000.318.2304.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Microsoft.UI.Xaml.dll

Жмете пуск и пишете eventvwr.msc, там заходите в Windows - Приложение, ну а там увидите все незарегестрированные ошибки своего приложения. У вас скорей всего 0xc000027b в пакете Microsoft.UI.Xaml.dll, а тут все дело в PublishTrimmed, который требуется для AOT. Я лично обхожу это все добавлением <EnableMsixTooling>true</EnableMsixTooling> в .csprog, но на сколько верное решение... а черт его знает)

EvgeniyZ, При добавлении свойства true приложение запускается.

Но также добавил свойство false, чтобы видеть все предупреждения после компиляции. И тут самое неприятное, исключений 66: AOT analysis warning IL3050, warning IL2026, warning IL2057. описание исключений говорит о том, что сборка не совместима с AOT.

"Запускается" - значит "вопрос решен", верно? Зачем вы тогда в нем изменили заведомо нерабочий код на тот, который не воспроизводит проблему? Что касается "исключений" - это не исключения, а предупреждения, которые говорят вам о том, что указанная в нем библиотека не поддерживает AOT, в чистом проекте это допустим WebView2, который достаточно только обновить (установить с Nuget). P.S. При упоминании не забывайт указывать @ (@ник), иначе человек не получит уведомления.

Вопрос по запуску решен, но как только добавляю привязку к кнопке через команду приложение сразу закрывается. В событиях тоже, что и ранее: Имя сбойного модуля: Microsoft.UI.Xaml.dll, Код исключения: 0xc000027b. Для WebView2 пакет Nuget установил на 4 предупреждения стало меньше, а что делать с остальными, есть какой-либо обходной путь?

Например: /_/src/libraries/System.Private.Xml/src/System/Xml/Serialization/CodeGenerator.cs(438): AOT analysis warning IL3050: System.Xml.Serialization.CodeGenerator.StackallocSpan(Type,Int32): Using member 'System.Type.MakeGenericType(Type[])' which has 'RequiresDynamicCodeAttribute' can break functionality when AOT compiling. The native code for this instantiation might not be available at runtime. Где найти этот атрибут RequiresDynamicCodeAttribute.

Я не могу воспроизвести вашу проблему. Можете составить минимальный пример на голом WinUI3, который будет выдавать эти предупреждения? На данный момент я создал голый проект, скопировал туда все ваши пакеты, добавил WindowsPackageType, TrimmerSingleWarn, PublishAot и EnableMsixTooling, создал простую команду при помощи MMVM Toolkit, которая просто выводит окно, в XAML привязал  (Command="{x:Bind ClickCommand}), далее собрал проект через студию, чистый лог сборки, ну и приложение запускается.

@EvgeniyZ, ссылку на GitHub можно разместить?

Как хотите, хоть архивом.

@EvgeniyZ, https://github.com/SiSharp20/TerminalClient.git

Я понял в чем проблема... Так, как я добавил у себя пакеты, но не использовал, при компиляции данный код убирался, из-за чего я не получал ошибок. Что касается ваших ошибок: AOT не всеми библиотеками, это все зависит уже от авторов данных библиотек и специфики их работы. В документации есть список того, что не поддерживает AOT и в нем можно заметить System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, который вы и используете. Собственно, вам надо избавиться от этого пакета, сообщений не будет.

@EvgeniyZ, понятно, спасибо за помощь и уделенное время.
